# Is it possible to Limite Bandwidth programatically on Android Application?

Tags: android

Does someone know if there is a way to limite the bandwidth of our Android application programatically ?

Thank You

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Limit the rate at which transfer is done? Cap it?  Capping it shouldn't be too hard, just calculate how much you've used. Note that different providers may track bandwidth differently so you can't always be 100% accurate

Comment: Application  will download lot of video all the time in background. But during period  my client want to limit the download speed to not use all bandwith

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an application you should may be able to control the rate at which you download content. See [Android: how to limit download speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19808396/android-how-to-limit-download-speed).

If the phone is rooted you may be able to leverage the OS to limit bandwidth. Either by using iptables or tc (traffic control). I believe this is how [BradyBound](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oxplot.bradybound) works

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to throttle your app so that it doesn't use too much bandwidth, use's the answer from Stu.

If you're looking to test low bandwidth scenarios, or run the app with a simulated, crummier data connection, you can do this in the debug settings of a device or on your emulator:  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html

Look for -netspeed and -netdelay to simulate different sorts of networking scenarios and connectivity.